# How do I download one google client api service without downloading all of them?

Tags: github, google-play-developer-api, google-client

I want to use the Google Play Android Publishing API for Java but I can't figure out how to download ONLY that API from GitHub. Is that even possible?

```
clients/google-api-services-androidpublisher/v3
```

I tried the following command but it didn't work.

```
git pull https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/clients/google-api-services-androidpublisher.git

fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Why should I have to download and compile EVERY client API service google makes just to use the one?